# I want to load "sponsored article links" before the comment section in the Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just migrated from blogger to Wordpress, The complete migration was successful.

The only problem I have is, Wordpress doesn't allow you to edit directly the full html code instead you have to edit the php files.

I have added my sponsored link snippet to Single Post.php below the

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

but I want to load the comments after the snippet 
So where should I put the snippet? and what is the correct way to do it in php?

**Here is the code:**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="mh-wrapper clearfix">
    <div id="main-content" class="mh-content" role="main" itemprop="mainContentOfPage"><?php
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            mh_before_post_content();
            get_template_part('content', 'single');
    mh_after_post_content();
        comments_template();

        endwhile; ?>

<div id="sponsored-widget"></div>

<script //soponsored link snippet 
</script>

    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What part of the code you posted is the 'snippet' you are trying to insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods:

### Method 1: Edit Directly

```
<?php ... mh_after_post_content(); ?>
    // Your Custom Codes
<?php comments_template();
```

### Method 2: Use WordPress Hooks

in your functions.php, add the code below:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_sponsored_widget', 10);
function my_sponsored_widget($content) {
    $sponsored_content = '<div id="sponsored-widget">Sponsored Content</div>';
    return $content . $sponsored_content;
}
```

in your situation, the theme implemented two action function `mh_before_post_content()` and `mh_before_post_content()`, they are used to insert custom content to before/after post content. I can't know the action hook name, but I guess it's should as same as function name. if it is, you can add your content like this:

```
add_action('mh_before_post_content', 'my_sponsored_widget', 10);
function my_sponsored_widget() {
    echo '<div id="sponsored-widget">Sponsored Content</div>';
}
```

Usually it's NOT a good practice that edit your theme file directly to customize your theme unless your are a theme developer. For theme users, you should use WordPress hook functions `add_filter()` or `add_action()` to change/insert something or search and use some WordPress plugins suite your need, there are tons of WP plugins can do what you want to do, for this case, I just googled and got two: [Simple Custom Content](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-content/) or [Add Widget after Content](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-content/).

Why should not edit theme directly? Because the theme may update in the future and you will need to modify/merge your custom codes on every update.

### Related Links

- //codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks
- //developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/
- //developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

P.S. I'm also new to Stackoverflow, so I can only include two links in my answer:)